# C++ std::vector<int> issue

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, stdvector

In the main function, I'm initializing a variable of type `std::vector <int>` like this:

```
std::vector <int> edges[9]
```

and then add my elements to it.

what i wanna know is there a way to initialize edges with variables ??
To do something like this: (already know that this writing gives error)

```
int n=9;
std::vector <int> edges[n]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set the size of the vector, use `std::vector<int> foo(9)`. What you are doing is initializing an array with nine separate vectors.

For a variable, you can do `std::vector<int> foo(n)`.

Comment: Fantastic answer, sir

Comment: It looks as OP was fine with having 9 vectors before, you are not really answering the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to have a vector initialized with "9" int space and you want to initialize the same with a particular value "10" for example

Here is how you can achieve the same.

```
  std::vector <int> edges;
  edges.resize(9);
  cout<<"size =>"<<edges.size()<<endl;
  std::fill(edges.begin(), edges.end(), 10);
```

`resize` reserves the initial size and `std::fill` can be used to fill the same with desired value.

Hope this helps

Comment: first of all, `std::vector::resize()`, is not actually, reserving, rather it directly affect the size of the vector as it  reallocates the vector with preferred size you provide. Secondly, there is no need of using `std::fill` here; instead a single line `std::vector <int> edges(9,10);` is needed for what you aimed to do.

Comment: jejo Thanks for the shortcut std::vector <int> edges(9,10).  I looked into the vector implementation and found that it does the same thing i.e resize + std::fill(..),